# DataPower API GW Service is in pending state

Tags: ibm-datapower

I've two physical DataPower appliance (v2018.4.x.x). Appliance 1 contains one of the API Domian (api-01) & Appliance 2 contains two domains (api-02 & api-03).

I'm facing issue with the API Gateway Service in api-01. The service when enabled is going in to pending state & doesn't comes up. All required objects are up. Peering in all domains is up.

API Gateway & API Gateway Service is up in api-02 & api-03.

In logs of api-01 I can only see below -

Request=kStart current state=kStarting current request=kStart

I tried disabling enabling the GW service, restarting domain & appliance but issue persist.